# How to find the largest and smallest possible number from an input integer?

Tags: c, codeblocks

I am trying to find the largest and smallest possible value from an integer which is taken as an input from the user. For example - If the user enters the number 3859428, I want to find 9885432 and 2345889.

Here is my code -:

```
  #include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int num[100], original, remainder, min=0, max=0, count=0, i, j;

    printf("Enter a number : ");
    scanf("%[^\n]", num);

    original = num;

    i=0;

    while(num!=0)
    {
        num/=10;
        num[i]=num;
        count++;
        i++;
    }

    for(i=0; i<count, num!=0; i++)
    {
        for(j=i+1; j<count, num!=0; j++)
        {
            if(num[i]<num[j])
            {
                min=min*10+num[i];
                num/=10;
            }
        }
    }

    while(min!=0)
    {
        remainder=min%10;
        max=max*10+remainder;
        min/=10;
    }

    printf("The difference between largest(%d) and smallest(%d) of the integer %d is %d.\n", max, min, original, max-min);
 
return 0; 

}
```

I am getting 2 errors -

> "assignment to expression with array type"

on line 16 and 29, and 2 warnings -

> "assignment to 'int' from 'int*' makes integer from pointer without a
> cast"

on line 10 and 17.

I don't know what these mean and how to accomplish my task. Any help would be great.

Thank You.

Comment: Given `int num[100]` and `num/=10;` --> Do you think you can divide an _array_ by 10?  What are you trying to accomplish with that division?

Comment: You are right. Sorry. I need help to accomplish my task but don't have any idea on how to do it. Can you give any suggestions?

Comment: First review, `int num[100]` ... `scanf("%[^\n]", num);`.  What type of data matches the specifier `"%[^\n]"`?  `num` will not work.
`

Comment: "%d[^\n]" is for getting input until user presses enter. My main aim is to find the largest and smallest possible combination from an input integer. That's why I used array because I don't know how to access individual digits. I am stuck.

Comment: What complier warning or error do you get with `scanf("%[^\n]", num);`?  If you get none, review your settings and enable all warnings.

Comment: I don't get any warning or error on that part. I am using Codeblocks. I don't know how to enable all warnings.

Comment: Rather than stop at "I don't know how to enable all warning", try searching "Enable all warnings on codeblocks" on the web.  GTG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you are trying to achieve is to *input some number*, and then *reorder it's digits* to achieve a maximum and minimum value:

```
int num[100];
scanf("%[^\n]", num);
```

First of all I would recommend either setting scanf() to parse the input to an integer:

```
int number;
scanf("%d", &number);
```

Or using an string (array of chars) to hold your digits one by one. (I'm going to continue this way).

```
//Initialize all elements to '\0', in order to know where the user input ended.
char digits[100] = {'\0'}; 
scanf("%99[^\n]", digits);  

/*Simply using scanf("%99s", digits) should work too.
No need to protect from the new line since we aren't doing any other calls to scanf().*/
```

**Note on scanf()**: As hinted in the comments to this answer, you may get a string overflow if you do not specify the maximum width of your string; instead of `scanf("%[^\n]", digits)`, consider `scanf("%99[^\n], digits)`. The width specifier should be the size of the length of your buffer minus one. (We need to make it one byte shorter so `scanf()` can add the string terminator (null character) at the end of our buffer, had we used all the space in it). You may also want to check if `scanf()` was successful by checking the return value:

```
/* We only have one string in our arguments, so scanf() should return 1.
If anything goes wrong, terminate the program*/
int numOfAssignments = scanf("%99[^\n]", digits);
if (numOfAssignments != 1) return 1;
// return numOfAssignments; may also be a good idea.
```

Consider using [fgets()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) instead, except you would have to manually remove the new line character.

**========= End of Note =========**

Let's make a define for the max number of digits, since we will be using it on most of the code: `#define MAX_SIZE 100`

Then, since you need to print the initial number at the end of the program, you were trying to copy it to a variable:

```
original = num;
```

Problem here is, that `int num[100]` (now `char digits[100])` is an array, and you were just copying it's address to `original`. To copy the whole number the user had given the program you would need to copy each element of the array, one by one (or we could use `memcpy()` instead):

```
for (i = 0; i < MAX_SIZE && i != '\0'; ++i){
    original[i] = digits[i];
}
```

I will actually use the `digits` array as my "original number" and will declare two extra arrays `maxDigits[MAX_SIZE]` and `minDigits[MAX_SIZE]` to hold the digits in ascending (min) and descending (max) order. Next, I will initialize either of the arrays:

```
minDigits[MAX_SIZE] = { '\0' };
maxDigits[MAX_SIZE] = { '\0' };

//Stop copying values when the null character is found, also count the number of digits.
while (digits[count] != '\0') {
    maxDigits[count] = digits[count++];
}
```

Now, since this is supposed to hold the digits in descending order, we have to sort the array (*this could probably have been done in the previous step, but this is about all the brainpower I have at 1:00 AM*).

```
//Look up Insertion Sort to learn about this sorting algorithm
int buffer; 
for (i = 1; i < count; ++i) {      
    buffer = maxDigits[i];
    j = i - 1;
    while (j >= 0 && maxDigits[j] < buffer) {
        maxDigits[j + 1] = maxDigits[j];
        j = j - 1;
    }
    maxDigits[j + 1] = buffer;
}
```

Now that `maxDigits` is sorted we need to sort `minDigits`.
This one should be easy, since all we need is to *flip* `maxDigits`:

```
for (i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    minDigits[i] = maxDigits[count - i - 1];
}
```

Of course, we need to calculate the difference between the maximum and minimum value of reordered digits, so we should convert `maxDigits` and `minDigits` to integers in order to do math with them:

```
/*This will multiply each digit with it's position value and add it together
(hundreds + tens + ones...)*/
int multiplier = 1;
for (i = count - 1; i >= 0; --i, multiplier *= 10) {
    max += (maxDigits[i] - '0') * multiplier;
    min += (minDigits[i] - '0') * multiplier;
}
/*Since the digits we stored are actually characters from '0' to '9' and not
integers 0 to 9, we need to substract the value of '0' or else our min and max values will be off.*/
```

Finally, we just have to output the results:

```
printf("The difference between largest(%d) and smallest(%d) of the integer %s is %d.\n", max, min, digits, max - min);
```

Comment: Thank You so much! And sorry for the late reply. I will shortly try your solution on my IDE and then ask any further question if needed. Again, thanks.

Comment: `scanf("%[^\n]", digits);` without a _width_ limit is worse than [`gets()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used).  Better as `scanf(" %99[^\n]", digits);`.  Even better: check the return value.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica You're right, I'll add a note on that.

Comment: @Raxus Although hard to see, there is a space between `"` and `%` to consume white-spaces in the line of code: `scanf(" %99[^\n]"`.  Useful for the _next_ `scanf()` to consume the left-over `'\n'`.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do can be done much simpler. There is no need to parse the input as a number at all, no need to convert it into binary form and then extract decimal digits from it to reorder them.

The same result can be achieved simply by reading a string and sorting it for the minimal number (potentially drop leading '0') and reversing it for the maximum.